# REST API naming confusion - how to name a resource that does an assignment?

Tags: api, rest, resources

I'm developing a REST API, and I've got the following tables in the DB: classes, subjects, classes_subjects; and the following resources: `http://api.example.com/class` resource for the classes table, and `http://api.example.com/subject` resource for the subjects table.

I would like to assign a subject to a class of students (e.g. assign Literature to class 1), i.e. save the class_id and subject_id in the classes_subjects table, but I've got a hard time figuring out how to name the new resource for the classes_subjects table.

I can't name it `http://api.example.com/assign` because that would be against REST principles, but it would also be awkward to name it `http://api.example.com/classes-subjects`

Should I just use the /class resource and use PUT when assigning a subject?

I can't figure out any noun to use for assigning subjects to classes. Does any of you know how to handle this kind of issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following schema:

- Get all classes with subject 123:

  ```
  GET /subjects/123/classes
  ```
- Associate a class with a subject:

  ```
  POST /subjects/123/classes?classId=<classId>
  ```

Comment: Great, thanks a lot !
However, is it ok if it works the other way around?

`GET /classes/15/subjects`

and 

`POST /classes/15/subjects?subjectId=<subjectId>`

so that I would get all the subjects assigned to class 15, and associate a subject with a class ?

Comment: @user1988372, Yes, that is perfectly ok too. You can consider also using PUT instead of POST. In that case you would do PUT /classes/15/subjects/<subjectId>